# How to set Image From SD Card in iText Pdf

Tags: android, itext

I want to set Image in pdf.i use iText for set Image in pdf.I Succsessfully Diaplayed image From Assets folder.But I want To display Image from sd card path.
following is code for display image from assets folder.

```
    try
    {
        InputStream ims = con.getAssets().open("prof_image.png");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        cell.addElement(image);
        //cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); //alignment
        //cell.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f)); //cell background color
        cell.setFixedHeight(60); //cell height
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what error message you are getting?? post your logcat here

Comment: i have not error,but i have not idea about how to display image from sd card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
        {
            String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gtu.png";
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

            //InputStream ims = con.getAssets().open("prof_image.png");
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_RIGHT);

            cell.addElement(image);
            //cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); //alignment
            //cell.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f)); //cell background color
            cell.setFixedHeight(60); //cell height
            table.addCell(cell);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```